# Substituting one engine for another in a tournament

Tags: engines, tournament

I am running a strong computer chess engine tournament, using arena 3.5.1 All engines are playing a large number of games. One engine appears to be glitching so I want to replace it with another alternative (in terms of CPU speed / compatibility) of the same version of the engine.

Is it possible to substitute one engine with another and retain the points that the other engine has already earned?

Comment: aren't YOU running the tournament ?

Comment: Yes. Hence why I am asking if there is a way of substituting and retaining the points. I know how to delete and engine and add another, but not how to retain / re-allocate points.

Comment: Are you using a tournament manager software? What is it?

Comment: I am running the tournament within Arena 3.5.1. If this is what you mean. All new territory for me.

Comment: @asibahi The question is about **how** to substitute a new version and not restart the tournament.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the old engine executable and copy a new one with the same filename to the same directory.